# Putting value in a props from child to parent in vue.js is Error

Tags: vue.js

Good day,

I'm trying to pass a value from child to parent using the props but I'm having an error that says,

`Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "search"`

Here are my sample codes:

Parent component

```
<template>
<div>
    <child :search="search" />
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default(){
    data: ()=>({
        search: ''
    })
}
</script>
```

Child component

```
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="search" />
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    props: ['search']
    watch:{
         search(val){
             this.$emit('search', val);
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding v-model to search. So if you type into your input vue to mutates the property. And it's just a warning which says that the data will be lost on next update, because then the property will passed again and your last value will be overwritten.

You could do something like this:

Child:

```
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="search" />
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    mounted () {
        this.searchForResult= this.search;
    },
    props: ['search'],
    data() {
        searchForResult: ''
    },
    watch:{
         searchForResult(val){
             this.$emit('search', val);
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

Parent:

```
<template>
<div>
    <child :search="search" />
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default(){
    data: ()=>({
        search: ''
    })
}
</script>
```

There is also the possibility to add a search method which you can call from parent.

Comment: where did you get the `initialSearch`?

Comment: you have to change in your parent, look at the edit

Comment: The mounted helped me

Comment: but I did something different

Comment: Please accept my modification of your answer. for other devs too :)

Answer (score 0):

Parent component

```html
<template>
<div>
    <div>received: {{childResult}}
    <child :search="search" @change="change" />
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default(){
    data(){
        return {
            search: 'some content',
            childResult: ''
        }
    },
    methods:{
        change(data){
            this.childResult = data;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Child component

```html
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text" v-model="result" />
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
    props: {
        search: String
    },
    data(){
        return {
            result: this.search
        };
    },
    watch:{
         result(val){
             this.$emit('change', val);
         }
    }
}
</script>
```